# My code returning 0 Actually it should return reverse of input

Tags: c, recursion, reverse

I wrote the following C code for school and I can't seem to find out why it returns 0. I have to use recursive number of digits and power functions to recursevely reverse the input number(the reverse function has to be a 1 parameter function):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int digits(int x)
{
    if(x!=0)
        return 1 + digits(x/10);
    else
        return 0;
}

int power(int x,int y)
{
    if(y!=1)
        return x*power(x,y-1);
    else
        return x;
}

int reverse(int x)
{
    static int nr=0;
    if(digits(x)!=1)
        return nr + power(10,digits(x)-1)*(reverse(x/10)%10);
    else
        return x;

}

int main()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d\n",reverse(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could start by putting some printf statements into each of your functions detailing the calling parameters and then the return value

Comment: Just as an idea: An iterative implementation of `reverse`, using just one single loop and fully reentrant, is only a handful of lines long, and may be much easier to reason about than your recursive approach.

Comment: I know it can be done easier, more simple and faster, but this is the approach I have to use for this school code

Comment: @RobertRozas Um. actually that should be `1`. In fact, it should be something like: `return 1 + ((x<10) ? 0 : digits(x/10));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you almost had it right, the only thing wrong was how you connected the recursive output.

just change :

```
return nr + power(10,digits(x)-1)*(reverse(x/10)%10);
```

to :

```
return power(10,digits(x)-1)*(x%10) + (reverse(x/10));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int reverse(int x)
{
    if ( !(x/10) ) 
        return x;
    else
        return (x % 10) * power(10,digits(x/10)) + reverse(x/10);
}
```